# select and click a button with CSS selector in C# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors

I want to click a button of a webpage, but I don't know how to select and click a button with Selenium.

The target source is below:

```
<span class="login-bt">
<a href="#" onclick="return sChangeURL('GB2101_KAIINLOGIN','https://north2.eplus.jp/sys/main.jsp')" >ログイン</a>
</span>
```

Here is my code.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;


class Test
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://north2.eplus.jp/sys/main.jsp?uji.verb=GGWP01_mousikomi&uji.bean=B.apl.web.JOAB070100Bean&uketsukeInfoKubun=001&ZScreenId=GGWA01&_ga=1.146803575.1900392715.1483976716");
    IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginId"));
    query.SendKeys("*******@gmail.com");

    IWebElement query2 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginPassword"));

    query2.SendKeys("******");


   IWebElement a = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("onclick=\"return"));

   a.Click();

}
}
```

I want to know how to select and click the login button. Thank you for reading.

Comment: this is your onclick: <a href="#" onclick="return sChangeURL('GB2101_KAIINLOGIN','https://north2.eplus.jp/sys/main.jsp')">ログイン</a>.... not "return".. I'd start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `onclick=\"return` is not a css selector.

You can try `[onclick~="return"]`to find elements that have the `onclick` attribute with the value starts with `return`, but **I really don't think** it's a good idea.

Another option is to target the anchor inside the `login-bt` class:

```
span.login-bt a
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But I couldn't understand the expression clearly. Is it an expression of XPath?

Comment: Which of them? There are two there (well... actually none of them is xpath)

Comment: Attribute selectors look like XPath predicates but are otherwise unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, for performance reasons, you should probably put an id on the button if you have control over the html that is rendered. Otherwise, keying off of the parent span as Dekel suggested is your best option.